# How do native addons affect node.js program?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, performance, node-native-addon

I have such codes:

```
const test = require('./build/Release/test');
console.time('js');
console.log(f(0, 0, 1000, 1000, 50.6));
console.timeEnd('js');
console.time('c++');
console.log(test.sum(0, 0, 1000, 1000, 50.6));
console.timeEnd('c++');
```

```
const test = require('./build/Release/test');
console.time('c++');
console.log(test.sum(0, 0, 1000, 1000, 50.6));
console.timeEnd('c++');
console.time('js');
console.log(f(0, 0, 1000, 1000, 50.6));
console.timeEnd('js');
```

They work correctly, give same results, everything is great, but the only problem is that in the first code JS f() takes ~15ms, but in the second example it takes ~3ms. And this results are stable (when I start the program more than once, it gives nearly same results). How can it be? Why does performance of the function on JS depends on calling the independent function from a native addon?

P.S. Here is the console from two runs of the program:

```
{"x": -151.932697, "y": 235.000000}
js: 17.064ms
{"x": -151.932697, "y": 235.000000}
c++: 7.908ms
```

```
{"x": -151.932697, "y": 235.000000}
c++: 8.191ms
{"x": -151.932697, "y": 235.000000}
js: 2.578ms
```

Comment: Your "benchmark" is very flawed, since you are only calling each function once. In order to minimize the influence of various other factors you need to run the functions multiple times and take the average. Also you may have to "warmup" the nodejs VM in order to get more accurate results

Comment: What does that mean: "warm up"?

Comment: And, as I said, I took average, and it is actually like that. The error may be 1-1.5 ms, but not 10ms

Comment: The code you show runs each function only once. Taking the average of multiple runs has the same issues, namely that you are including the time that nodejs spends on compiling your JS code (and trying to optimize it) in the measurements

Comment: ahh. I understood. I will make one more counting in a moment

Comment: I ran it 1e7 times in a loop and I got the same result: if js is executed before addon, it takes `js: 2.782s`, but if after - `js: 1.983s`.

Comment: You are very likely still having VM warmup time affecting your measurements. You should prefer using a proper benchmarking library instead of writing your own tests - there is a lot of important points that have to be taken into account (and it's hard to get them all right)

Comment: so it is mostly because the program "warms up"? After it works with addon it starts working faster ("warms up") and executes js faster, am I right?